# Images loading a bit slow in ListView using AsyncTask

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-listview, android-imageview

How can i optimize my code to load the images lightening quick? I mean after scrolling up and down fast , it takes a couple of seconds or more to load the image into the `ImageView` of my `ListView`. Here is my sample code of my adapter :

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
        String album_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        text.setText(title);
        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.valueOf(album_id));
        iv.setTag(uri);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_holo_dark);
        new MyImageLoader(context,view,iv,uri).execute(uri);

    }

private class MyImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap>{
        Context context;
        View v;
        ImageView iv;
        Uri u;

        MyImageLoader(Context context,View v,ImageView iv,Uri u){
            this.context = context;
            this.v = v;
            this.iv = iv;   
            this.u = u;
        }
        protected synchronized Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... param) {
            ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = res.openInputStream(param[0]);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return artwork;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp){
            if(bmp!=null)
            {   ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                if(iv.getTag().toString().equals(u.toString()))
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    //iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, false));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two things I can think of:

1. starting in ICS the AsyncTask is a singlethread thing, that means, if you fire 10 AsyncTasks, it will complete the 1st, then go to the 2nd, then the 3rd, always waiting the others to complete before carry on. You can use the `.executeOnExecutor` method of it to running the tasks parallel with more threads.
2. Use a LruCache to do a RAM cache of your images. This [video from Google IO 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM) shows exactly how to make a LruCache (I always suggest people to watch the whole video because there's a lot of cool tricks)

Comment: `1.` I can't do it since I am targetting GB.
`2.` I will try this and get back to you.  
`3.` Is there any optimization I can do it make it faster ? I mean in the existing code. Rather than caching. Caching I know will make it faster.  
`4.` Can I use HashMap rather than LRU cache to make stuff easier ?

Comment: 1. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html 2. ok 3. not that I can see without building it myself and doing some closer debugging. 4. No. Use LruCache. A HashMap will eventually crash your app with OutOfMemory error. But believe me, the LruCache is VERY simple, just those few lines you can see on the slide on 4:30

Answer (score 0):

Try [`BitmapFun.zip`](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) with compatibility library works great on Android 2.3!

Or if you don't want at any chance compatibility library  you can try the (older version) `ImageDownloader`:

- http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/
- http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html